# How to use locally modified nested NPM dependency?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

Say I'm working on project `A`,

`A` depends on NPM package `B` which is published by others.

`B` depends on another package `C`.

Now, I found a bug in `C` and it's causing failures in `A`, so I forked `C`, cloned onto my machine and fixed the bug locally.

**The question is**: how can I use/test the locally modified `C` without waiting until the authors of `B` and `C` update their packages?

I ran `yarn link` in my locally updated `C`'s directory but I have no idea how to let dependency `B` pick up the yarn link. One solution might be to clone `B` onto my local machine and `yarn link B` too, but it does not seem to be an elegant approach.

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to do the same for package B and modify the dependency for package C. Then you can a) add you github repos as dependencies or b) publish your modified packages to npm.